# how to read cgi file by javascript

Tags: javascript, cgi

How do I use the output of a CGI program in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Same way you read any other server page: AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

If your cgi file is placed inside web root directory, you can use Ajax to receive its content. jQuery sample:

```
var cgiContent ='';
$.get('cgi-bin/my.cgi', function(data) {
    cgiContent = data;
});
```

Comment: *If your cgi file is placed inside web root directory* No. Your code says the cgi script is inside `./cgi-bin/`. Other than that, it's a helpful answer (at least helped me a lot). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your cgi output javascript commands in text and then include its output as you would include any other javascript file.

**CGI Example in Python:**

```
print("Content-Type: text/plain")
print

print("var value = 'Hello World';")
```

**Then include this in your HTML page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/cgi/script.py"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(value)</script>
```